# Within my adhoc specific function how do I add commas when printing a list of integers

Tags: list, function, haskell, printing, tuples

With input being:

```
"I am what I
am, and I (765) do not like Spam. Abc2. Abc3."
```

My code makes an output of:

```
abc 2
am 1 2
and 2
do 2
i 1 2
like 2
not 2
spam 2
what 1
```

Where each word is listed along with the line number it appears on.

Question: How do you print the statement below where you get commas between the line numbers like so:

```
abc 2
am 1,2
and 2
do 2
i 1,2
like 2
not 2
spam 2
what 1
```

Here is the code I have that takes a list with tuples formatted like this

`[([1, 2], "a"), ([1], "b"), ([1], "c"), ([2], "dd")]`

and prints it into my current output which I listed above:

```
combineInts listTuple = map f $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sortBy (compare `on` fst) $ map swap listTuple
    where f xs@(x:_) = (map snd xs, fst x)

printListTuples listTuple = unlines [ ys ++ " " ++ unwords (map show x) | (x, ys) <- listTuple ]
```

If I can get help figuring out how to get those commas in between the line numbers it would be useful and be much more readable.

Comment: is that code you wrote?

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way, and there's a hard way. The easy way is to use the `Show` instance for lists and a couple really simple list functions. The other really simple way is to use just one list function. Cn you see how? The harder bit more educational) way is to write it yourself. Can you come up with the base *cases* and the recursive case?

Comment: Well 'show' is being used in printListTuples to accomplish some of what you're telling me (my understanding at least), but I'm not sure what function to use to insert commas.

Comment: @shamu11,  I thought of a nicer way. Just remember that strings are lists, and read the documentation for `Data.List` on Hackage. You'll find something that suits your needs perfectly.